# How to solve an error in gains for vectors of equal length

Tags: r

I keep getting an error in gains telling me that the actual and predicted vectors are not of equal length. Below you will see that I ran length() for each vector and they are indeed the same. What other reason could I be missing that is causing this error?

Thank you!

Partial Output:

```
> library(gains)
> Mowers.df$ownership = as.factor(Mowers.df$Ownership)
> prob = as.factor(prob)
> length(Mowers.df$Ownership)
[1] 24
> length(prob)
[1] 24
> gain = gains(Mowers.df$OWnership, prob, groups=24)
Error in gains(Mowers.df$OWnership, prob, groups = 24) : 
  Error: The actual and predicted vectors are not of equal length
```

UPDATE: Seeing the output I noticed that I had a capital letter in Ownership that should not have been there. When I fixed that typo, I got this error instead:

```
> gain = gains(Mowers.df$Ownership, prob, groups=24)
Error in gains(Mowers.df$Ownership, prob, groups = 24) : 
  Error: The vector of actuals is not numeric
```

Comment: (a) I'd suggest editing the question to focus on the current problem - we don't need to have a record of you correcting your typo. (b) So, what is the `class()` of the actuals vector?

Comment: (c) You're using `>` in your question, which formats text as quoted. Use three backticks on their on line before and after code for code formatting (I'll edit to fix).

Comment: Looks like `actuals` is the first argument name - you're passing `Mowers.df$Ownership` there. The error says it needs to be numeric, but you convert it to `factor` with `as.factor` - don't do that. You can convert it back with `Mowers.df$Ownership = as.numeric(as.character(Mowers.df$Ownership))`. I'm also skeptical about making `probs` a factor - why?

Comment: Thank you Gregor. The class() of the actuals vector is Factor

Comment: If you need more help, please make your example reproducible by sharing some data - `dput()` is a good method for this, e.g., `dput(Mowers.df$Ownership[1:10])` for the first 10 values, and similarly for `prob`.

Comment: Thank you Gregor, that worked for this problem!